# Can a child Workitem inherit a field value from a parent in azure devops?

Tags: azure, tfs, devops, workitem

Im trying to find a way to let any new created child workitem, inherit the Tags value from its parent in Azure Devops.

I've searched and found that there is a way to Create a Rule from the Process template. but I cant find the Tags value.

Anyone have tried to do this before ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We do not have any build-in feature or rule to achieve this.

There has been a [similar feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/385158/copying-field-values-from-parent-work-item-by-crea.html) which raised by others.  You can vote and comment for this suggestion. When there are enough communities vote and added comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

[image]

Also, as a workaround, you could use some 3rd-party tool such as [TFS Aggregator (Web Service)](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) to achieve what you want. You can set and configure apply certain rules (such as copying fields from a parent item to a child item). And it will trigger after a work item is created or saved.